# Ignore "temp" files?

Tags: python

I've had a script for a while that has been running without issues however recently had a "hitch" with a temporary file that was within a directory.

The file in question started with '~$' on a windows PC so the script was erroring out on this file as it is not a proper DOCX file. The file in question was not open and occurred after being transferred of a network drive onto an external hard drive. Checking the destination drive (with hidden files on etc) did not show this file either.

I have attempted a quick fix off:

```
for (dirpath,dirnames,filenames) in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.docx'):
            filesList.append(os.path.join(dirpath,filename))    

for file in filesList:
    if file.startswith('~$'):
        pass
        else:
                <rest of script>
```

However the script appears to be ignoring this to proceed then error out again, as the file is not "valid".

Does anyone know either why this isn't working or a quick solution to get it to ignore any files that are like this? I would attempt a if exists, however the file technically does exist so this wouldn't work either.

Sorry if its a bit stupid, but I am a bit stumped as to A. why its there and B. how to code around it.

Answer (score 1):

In the second code block, your variable `file` contains the whole file path, not just the file name.

Instead skip the "bad" files in your first block instead of appending to the list:

```
for (dirpath,dirnames,filenames) in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.docx'):
            if not filename.startswith('~$'):
                filesList.append(os.path.join(dirpath,filename))
```

The other option would be to check `os.path.basename(file)` in your second code block.

Comment: This works with my test data here now, when I was working with the data at another location, it didn't work with the 2nd block for the if it starts with...

Thanks - I'll give this a test on a larger data set and pass this also to the other location to see if it doesn't crap out. My fix earlier was just to move everything away then back after deleting the folder as this cleared the file in question out